# Facebook like button doesn't work anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Sometime ago I made a like button for my website with the help of this tool: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and it worked well, the visitor could like the page and also make a comment.

Recently I noticed that the like button doesn't work anymore, when I click it the count goes +1 for a second then reverts back, also the comment windows appears and disappears as quickly.

I have searched the internet and found that I know have to have an appid, so I got one and added to my existing headers for facebook

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.myurl.com/url.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myurl.com/my/image/url.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Jocurile.US" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="ro_RO" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1058594454" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="294633860579624" />
```

Checked it with http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it doesn't give any errors, but my like button still doesn't work.

The integration code that I use on my page is

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
        <fb:like href="<?php echo $canonical;?>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="400" show_faces="false" colorscheme="dark" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

I haven't written my url because I don't want people to think I want likes but if it's necessary I will give you the url.

Comment: It doesn't work but what in more details? Is like button appearing? Is it clickable? Is the problem after click? Please make it more clear or write your URL with your Like button.

Comment: So, did you manage to take a look at the page? Is something wrong with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find what is wrong.

Comment: I have found why my like button doesn't work, it was blocked by facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that the culprit was the facebook button color scheme.
People had to confirm that they liked my page but the button was showing the text colored in white over a white background, because the color scheme was dark.